# OpenShift idling, rationale - just a service differentiation?

Tags: openshift

Have found several SO Q&A's related to OpenShift's concept of application idling when there is no inbound traffic for 24 hours. Apart from the fact that there could be hacks to work around it, I was wondering, as to what is the effect since OpenShift claims that the application is brought back to full live state when an incoming request is encountered. In that case, apart from the fact that the HTTP request that causes application to go back from idle state to live/running state would run trifle slower, but is there any other inconvenience that I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the first call after idling consistently fails. Subsequent calls do work then. This is probably due to a timeout, since it takes a while to spin up the gears. It may also depend on the time your application takes to activate, meaning this could be specific for my kind of application.

However I switched from the *FREE* plan to *BRONZE* a while ago and did not experience any problems since then.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this insight about the 1st request after spin-up failing. This is definitely contrary to what OpenShift appears to claim, unless I misinterpreted.

Comment: I did the upgrade to BRONZE about 3 months ago. There is no idling anymore, so I highly recommend the switch. If your site has little traffic, there is no difference in price to the FREE plan.